# Where the third div came from?

Tags: html, css

I was learning CSS variables and doing some basic stuff.

```css
/* Variables names must start with -- */
/* They are accessed with var(--name) */

:root {
    --clr: blue;
    --bgc: whitesmoke;
}

div{
    height: 20vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: var(--bgc);
    margin: 50px;
}

.hello{
    color: var(--clr);
}

.world{
    color: var(--clr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="variables.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hello"></div>
    <div class="world"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I ran the HTML using live-server in VS code.
I got a third and extra div out of nowhere.

[image]

which had the following properties

[image]

Comment: There's a comment there, `<!-- Code injected by live-server -->`, so I expect it was injected, probably by live-server...

Comment: Is this the same code? A not properly closed div might be the cause.

Comment: never ever write a CSS to target `div`, Use classes/ID or you will have a lot of headaches with all the online tools (codepen, jsfiddle, the SO snippet, etc, etc). All of them will add extra element for different purpose

Answer (score 1):

The extra div (and its inner div) is injected by the live server you are using.

While its inner div has `display:none` so you don't see it, your CSS has set a height and background color on all divs. This means the outer injected div is visible.

It picks up the `background-color: var(--bgc)` and the variable --bgc has been set as whitesmoke in root.

You could try running your code just from your browser on your PC and you should see just the Hello and World divs without anything extra being injected.

Comment: I actually realized that the problem was due to the Live Server and ran the code directly and the problem was solved. But now I understand why the div was visible. I should not target all divs.